# Why does my computer constantly crash (even in the UEFI)?

Tags: memory, bsod, crash

My wife got a computer (FHD Touchscreen All-in-One Desktop, AMD Ryzen 7 5700U, 12GB RAM) from her grandfather a year or so ago from [amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09JWC1BQH) and the computer would occasionally go to a BSOD [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4e9n.png). The rate of these BSODs occurring rapidly increased but for whatever reason the computer wouldn't allow a factory reset so I installed Linux Mint and deleted the Windows partition to see if that would fix the issue. It didn't fix the issue so I switched to Fedora 39 to see if the problem still persisted, which it did.

I did some research online (I'm a data scientist so hardware isn't exactly my trade) and found that bad RAM can often be the cause of these issues. I tried running some tests in the UEFI including a memory test but the computer would crash and the screen would freeze  while the computer's power remained on after roughly 5-10 seconds of testing. I just replaced the RAM and when that didn't work I thought I would try asking you.

It's hard to even log in to the computer without the computer freezing so I'm not able to run any tests. The computer also doesn't seem to have enough time to warm up so it doesn't seem like it's an overheating issue.

Comment: I would suggest to take the computer to be repaired, if there's no warranty.

Comment: On another computer create a USB stick with memtest86 (https://www.memtest86.com/) and boot from that USB stick.

Comment: @Whitesnack - Someone local to you, since we don’t know where that is and have absolutely no need to know where that is, just ask whomever you find for a quote on their diagnostic services. **Do not** tell us anything about where you live we cannot and will not help you find a computer repair technician.

Comment: Could be the power supply slowly deteriorating. The output likely has electrolytic caps to smooth the DC, and those can go bad. If you can, try substituting another PSU, or, if familiar with electronics work, put a large capacitor in parallel with the DC line.

Comment: why is there no mention of the BSOD error code in your post?